# Is there "No show" for trains in combined tickets?

Tags: tickets, cancellations, air-france

For example, Air France offer some tickets that combine flight and train to the final destination. After I arrive at CDG, if I don't take the train to the final destination, are they able to see whether or not I took the SNCF train?

If they can see it, will they cancel the return tickets for train and flight? It is important for me to understand this.

And if they really check, can I go to the train station, and then just leave the station? It's hard to believe they check whether I went to the final destination, right? I hope someone knows how this works.

Comment: i just saw in the Air France website they wrote: "SPECIAL RULES FOR TICKETS ON "TRAIN + PLANE" AND "PLANE + TRAIN" TRIPS
If you are traveling on a "train + plane" trip, you must first complete the train leg to validate your plane ticket.
If you are traveling on a "plane + train" trip, you must first complete the plane leg to validate your train ticket." https://goo.gl/3a4aTd  So I guess it doesn't really matter if they can see if i took the train, because i still will have to start the back leg from the train and i won't be able to do it if I won't go to final destination.